# Mighty Morphing Power Rangers-Megazord Origins?

Tags: power-rangers, mighty-morphin-power-rangers

When a Power Ranger summons a Megazord it would come from the ground, the ocean, or even a volcano if I recall correctly. So with these massive weapons essentially buried below the Earth, I would always wonder who exactly put them there?

Comment: As five year olds we never questioned it. Now... it doesn't even appear to have an answer!

Comment: I know but let's go back to that summer in the mid 1990's when MMPR was at a feverish high and take this premise entirely to seriously.Let's assume Zordon, a disembodied entity, came to earth and had seen dinosaurs then has a army of multicolored robots built-up after these creatures then buried them as a strategy to fight any evil that should come about...did poor Alpha have to do all the building and digging? Aye yai yai!!!

Answer (score 5):

In the first episode of Power Rangers Zeo we see the Command Center, which had been destroyed by a massive explosion at the end of Mighty Morphin Power Rangers (Season 3), be completely rebuilt in a matter of minutes.  The only visible cause is a form of energy that encompasses each piece of the superstructure before it reassembles.

This energy is visually similar to the energy that surrounded the original five Rangers during their initial teleportation/abduction.  Thus, it stands to reason that one of the surviving parts of the Command Center (the subterranean areas) housed some form of equipment that managed the teleportation and construction machinery.

If Zordon or the equipment under his control in the Command Center was capable of building a structure the size of an observatory within a few minutes, it stands to reason that the same sort of equipment would be capable of constructing the Zords.

We also know that the Zords are tied into the Morphing Grid, the source of the Ranger's powers.  Thus, we can assume that the Grid itself aids in the construction of the Zords.

In fact, in MMPR Season Two, we see this in action: the ThunderZords are initially summoned as the first season's DinoZords, before being transformed into the new ThunderZords.

[image: Mastadon Dinozord to Mastadon Lion Thunderzord]

The energy which encompasses the 'Zords during this transformation is visually identical to that which was used to rebuild the Command Center.

In short, Zordon (or machinery controlled by him) builds the Zords, using power from the Morphing Grid.

Answer (score 4):

In the 1995 **Mighty Morphin Power Rangers: the Movie** there is a text crawl, made specifically for those who came into the film with *absolutely NO knowledge* of the franchise (as if such a creature *existed* in the 90s). This text provided the essential backstory to the Rangers, while also increasing the scope of the plot, making it less about a space wizard and witch fighting it out using teens as proxies, and more of a eons old battle between the forces of good and evil. It went as follows:

Now it's clearly stated that "A legendary Inter-dimensional being known as Zordon came to the city of Angel Grove to establish a command post against evil." He sought out the teenagers and gave them the power to transform, as well as to call on the "colossal assault vehicles known as Zords."

Now, although this film *slightly* differs to the main show continuity, all of the fundamentals are the same: Teenagers with attitude are recruited by ancient powerful galactic being who *gives them* their powers, abilities and weapons, tasking them with protecting good on their home world. The 2017 movie *basically* follows the same format.... difference being this time around, **Zordon himself** was an ancient Ranger, and we *see him* place the Power coins in the earth and command them to find worthy successors....

Since the coins, powers, and Zords are all connected, it's safe to say that it was *Zordon,* with the aid of Alpha 5, who originally set the Zords up in their hiding spaces.

This makes sense because Zordon *does* possess teleportation technology, and thus can pretty much shunt things and people wherever he so wishes. This is supported by the fact that every time they are called, we (the audience) *see* the Zords emerge from **very** different areas (an earth fissure, a frozen glacier, a dessert, a jungle, and an *active volcano* ) before they.... *somehow* ...meet up and converge on the battlefield. Most usually, that means the mountain ranges outside of Angel Grove, or some miraculously only partly inhabited industrial part of the city proper.

So the Zords aren't actually "buried below the earth"; each one probably has an established "pen"/recharging station where they go to hibernate after the battles. We just *see* them seeming to pop out of these hidden lairs from different locations around the globe. More than likely, the Zords are transported from these environments where they go to "sleep"; the lairs being all "spread out" was likely an extra security measure. This tactic would keep each Zord safe from being located by the enemy when they are at rest.

Furthermore, if we think about it, there is *no logical way* that the city of Angel Grove, USA, converges on **all** of these disparate environments (it's somewhere in California, so while I could buy the dessert and fissure being close by, the ice tundra, jungle, and volcano are *all* big Nos.) *Further* furthermore, there would be *no safe way* for the Zords to emerge from their spaces **without** dimensional teleportation! *Forget* Jason's T-Rex starting casual earth quakes or Zack's mastodon having to run at *Mach 45* to reach him from the Arctic in seconds; Kimberly's Zord **alone** would cause volcanic eruptions *every time* they had to face a monster, and thus endangering any nearby populace on the *daily*!

So more than likely the Zords aren't just teleported through Space... but also through *Time* to get to the Rangers, each Zord passing through its own unique portal to reach their master in the present area and era. Naturally, they'd be teleported back to their original hiding spots when the threat is neutralized.

There *is* actually a precedence for this: in the *MMPR/Justice League* cross over, after Lord Zedd attacks the command center, a teleporter malfunction drops the Rangers accidentally into the world of the Justice League. We see that the Rangers still have their powers (so they are still connected to the Grid, and presumably "Their" earth), and when they call their Zords, the mechs appear to them *instantaneously* via a portal...

[image]

Keep in mind, this is a **Whole other dimension** Kim's Zord had to pass through to reach her, and there was no difficulty. So it's not far-fetched to say something similar has to happen when the Zords are called on in their *own* dimension in real time.